New Windows mail client installed, old client keeps asking for password
I've got new outlook (mail client) installed on W11 after a lot of resistance to it.  Anyway, I changed the password on one of the accounts in new outlook.  Now, whenever I login, old outlook asks for the password.
Is there any way of suppressing this?
Clarification
I am using the default mail client which comes with windows: not outlook from the MS Office suite.  It appears as Mail on the menu but when I hover over the item on the taskbar, the tooltip says Outlook.  I can't remember what it used to say before as it won't let me switch back to the old email client.
When I login, somehow the old mail client detects that it has the wrong password and asks me to correct it.  When I open the mail client, it flashes the old mail client, then switches to the new mail client, which pops up after 3-5 seconds, I can see all the emails, so there is nothing to correct.
I would like to stop the old mail client from popping up the message about the password being incorrect.

Have you tried entering the password?

I've entered the password and can read the email in new outlook.  Do I have to switch back to old outlook and change the password as well whenever I change passwords?

Why would you need to switch back to the old client to change the password? The old client has already probably been removed from your system. The password I assumed was to the email account and the current password would have to be entered into either client

" Now, whenever I login, old outlook asks for the password." Why do you need two versions of the Outlook client? Uninstall the old one.

How do I install the old one?  MS just switched me to the new one with an option to switch back to the old one.

You don't need to uninstall the old one. Just keep it there because the new outlook lacks certain features. Its great to have the old one as a fallback. For example, there's no PST import/export in the new outlook.

It's something I've come across a few times after insider updates, get a popup saying 'fix account' in the accounts section in Settings.
If you plan on sticking with the new client that Microsoft forces everyone to install and use, I suggest uninstalling the old Mail App using PowerShell if it keeps showing the notification.
The terminal needs Admin privileges to run the cmd:
Get-AppxPackage windowscommunicationsapps | Remove-AppxPackage
If Windows hasn't already uninstalled it as people have noted (Note: it never removed it on my device after Outlook was forcefully installed).
I was surprised upon trying to run the Mail app it would  just force close it immediately & open Outlook, I couldn't even change the Default Program options back as the Mail app; wouldn't show in app options.
Because of this I thought I'd lost years of emails, as I had removed the originals from Google's server to stop them complaining about space availability on my account. It also didn't keep any of my settings from the old Mail client.
Thankfully after uninstalling new Outlook, disabling its resurrect task and backup copy, I used PSEXEC to get access to my email database in WindowsApps to back it up. I even had to reset app data for Mail, as after uninstalling Outlook, Mail would still force close when attempting to open it.

I understand this app and MS' behavior surrounding it is exceptionally frustrating to you. Please note that this section is reserved for answers to the problem presented by OP. I have removed and cleaned up as much of the information I felt conveyed your frustration but still kept things professional and focused on the bit of solution you do present. Please recognize that this site isn't an open discussion forum. There are well presented and real problems, and clear answers.

It seems like your new password has not been updated in the classic Outlook’s saved credentials. Here are the steps to update your password in classic Outlook: Go to Control Panel > User Accounts > Manage your credentials, select credentials for Microsoft, Outlook or Lync and choose Remove
Deleting the OST (Offline Storage Table) file can sometimes resolve issues with Outlook, especially if the file has become corrupted. The OST file is where Outlook stores a local copy of your mailbox data, so you can continue working even when not connected to the internet.
Here are the steps to delete the OST file:

Close Outlook.
Press Win + R to open the Run dialog box.
Type %LOCALAPPDATA%\\Microsoft\\Outlook\\ and press Enter. This will open the folder where Outlook data files are stored.
Look for the OST file that corresponds to your email account. It should be named something like youremail@domain.com.ost.
Delete this file.

When you restart Outlook, it will download a fresh copy of your mailbox data from the server and create a new OST file.
Please note: Deleting the OST file will only delete the local copy of your mailbox data. The original data on the server will not be affected. However, any changes you made while offline that have not yet been synced to the server will be lost. So, make sure Outlook is online and all changes have been synced before you delete the OST file.
If above doesn't help, it is recommended that you delete the old profile and create a new profile and re-add your account: Go to control panel > mail > show profiles.

Deleting the OST really is not necessary, and is bad advise for people with slow internet connections. Especially given this is a question about entering the password, mentioning OST removal is not a good idea. Similarly as if your car runs out of fuel, your advise is: you need to go to the gas station to fill it up, but I've heard some people have problems with their tires, so you better also replace your tires.

"Outlook New" is a free version of outlook that has become the default windows mail client. It is not a replacement for Outlook Desktop client that is part of Office ! If you have Outlook Desktop with Office, uninstall "Outlook New" and never look back. Outlook new has ads, scans your mails 'anonymously' and has more telemetry then ever before.
